# チャットに移されたコメントの本来の投稿日時を確認したい

Tags: サポート

[この質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/40568/iphone%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E7%94%B3%E8%AB%8B%E6%99%82-xcode%E3%81%A7archive%E5%BE%8C%E3%81%AEvalidate%E3%83%9C%E3%82%BF%E3%83%B3%E3%81%8C%E6%8A%BC%E3%81%9B%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84) で1日〜2日の間コメントをやりとりしたのですが、チャットに移されたようです。チャットをみてみるとコメント当時の投稿日時が確認できませんでした。本来の投稿日時は破棄されてしまったのでしょうか？

質問の解決後、Teratailとのマルチポストを知り、双方同じ答えにたどり着いていたので、「はてどっちがより早く答えを出せたのかな？」と思い、日時を確認したかったのですが、今からでも確認する方法はありますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

少し見てみましたが、一般ユーザーがこれを確認する方法はなさそうです。。

コメントのチャットへの移動は、以下のように行われている模様です。

1. チャットルームを作る
2. 今あるコメントをすべてそこに新規投稿する
3. 今あるコメントをすべて削除する

削除されたコメントの日時は、モデレータならば確認できるので、具体的にどの投稿の日時が知りたいかをおっしゃっていただくと、それをお伝えすることはできると思います。

Comment: どもです〜。1番古いほうから数えて9つ目でじぶんが「だとすると、……」と書いているコメントの日時が知りたいです。

Comment: @dokubeko 「だとすると、単に無料アカウントだからという可能性が高いです。デベロッパプログラムに参加する必要があると思います。こちらで‌​も無料アカウントではボタン三つともグレー‌​アウト、有料アカウントでは問題ないことは‌​確認できました」のコメントですね、 12/28 11:55 (日本時間) に作成された投稿の様子です。

Comment: それです！　助かりました〜。こっちが早かったんだ✌︎